# Docker - run two processes in single container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, docker, docker-compose, microservices

I've created Ruby on Rails project with Nginx. Rails app and Nginx runs in separate and linked containers. This configuration works fine. However...

**1) Is it possible to run both together (Rails / Puma server + Nginx) in a single container?**

**2) How should the CMD command in Dockerfile look like?**

**3) What command should I use as the "command:" attribute in docker-compose.yml?**

I think that configuration to run them in separate containers is better solution, but I would like to get to know all possibilites.

*I use Puma as a Rails' app server and to run it I use command: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, docker monitors one single process, and the container is finished / relaunched (depending on launch flags) when this monitored process ends.

There is a specific distribution which aims at doing what you are pursuing, i.e., have more than one process alive in the docker instance while monitoring / restarting all of them, this image is phusion/baseimage, you will find it here: https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker

On this image, what you do is that you create as many services as you want by creating subdirectories under /etc/service, and launching as CMD the one who will start and monitor all the services, like this:

```
# Use phusion/baseimage as base image. To make your builds reproducible, make
# sure you lock down to a specific version, not to `latest`!
# See https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/blob/master/Changelog.md for
# a list of version numbers.
FROM phusion/baseimage:<VERSION>

# Use baseimage-docker's init system.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

# ...put your own build instructions here...

# Clean up APT when done.
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

After that, just ensure you are creating a folder per service under /etc/service, and that inside there is a file called "run". This will be the entry point for your service, an example (from the doc) of the Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir /etc/service/memcached
ADD memcached.sh /etc/service/memcached/run
```

So for your target, just create a couple of folders + run file, one for NGINX and other for the Rails/Puma server, and use this image as base.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I need.